# Geonames Search API Result does not contain all alternate names

Tags: api, geonames

The entity 5124497 ("Lindenhurst") has an alternate name "Breslau":

https://www.geonames.org/5124497/lindenhurst.html

However, when using the search API the alternate name "Breslau" is not included:

http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=USERNAME&style=full&name=Lindenhurst

Even though the alternate name "Breslau" is not included, the entity is included in the results for a `name=Breslau` search:

http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=USERNAME&style=full&name=Breslau

Other examples for this API behavior are:

- https://www.geonames.org/3100300/dobrowo.html, alternate name: "Post
  Danzig"
- https://www.geonames.org/5090215/town-of-newbury.html, alternate
  name: "Danzig"
- https://www.geonames.org/3099433/gulf-of-gdansk.html, alternate name: "Gulf of Danzig"

It seems that if the `lang` attribute of an alternate name is missing,  the alternate name is never included in the API result (although the entity can be found via an API search for the alternate name).

Is this a bug in the API or is this behavior intended? (How) is it possible to get all the alternate names?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I also would like to retrieve alternate names from API service, but no chance to do it